# Email without SSL

Tags: email, ssl, smtp, pop3, google-workspace

I have been trying to setup [LabTech Email settings](http://docs.labtechsoftware.com/documentation/LabTech2013#Configuration/Email/ConfiguringEmail.htm).
Unfortunately, it accepts only email settings that are not encrypted; no SSL/TLS
i.e POP 110 and SMTP 25. Tried to setup SMTPSSL in the same, but no help.

We have our email hosted on a GApps account, so there is no option of opting out of SSL.
I have read about setting up [Hmail Server](http://support.labtechsoftware.com/component/k2/item/870.html) and [STunnel](http://forums.labtechsoftware.com/viewtopic.php?t=15343) but our Labtech server is hosted on an EC2 by LabTech where we dont have access to setup mail servers.

I have tried with Restricted Gmail SMTP server ([aspmx.l.google.com](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en)), but POP is still a mess. Also, could not successfully figure out SMTP settings.

What i want:

1. Any free email that allows SSL-less authentication(and forward all emails to my support email)
2. An alternative to installing mail server on the hosted dedicated-application server(as i have no access to it)

Any any help is greatly appreciated.

**Update:**
Requirements:

1. Bypass SSL authentication of GMAIL service

   or
2. Setup to redirect mail, but could be installed outside of dedicated server

Comment: I don't know if I understand you correctly: Having SMTP only on port 25 and POP only on port 110 doesn't mean you cannot use SSL.  Okay, actually it does in the SMTP/POP-inside-SSL-sense, but the other way around might still work:  Did you try out whether STARTTLS works?  You could figure this out by `telnet`ing to the server and ask it politely (`telnet <host> 25` and typing `EHLO myhostname.example.com` and look out whether it includes `STARTTLS` into the response).  SSL-ports for SMTP, POP and IMAP (465/tcp, 995/tcp and 993/tcp resp.) are deprecated.

Comment: @AndreasWiese yes. i have tried with the ports 25, 587, 465 for SMTP and 110,995 for POP3. Nothing helped :(

Comment: @AndreasWiese this is the reply '250-IP-0A832BDF
250-SIZE 20480000
250 AUTH LOGIN'

Comment: Question seeking for service recommendations ( i.e. email providers ) are not on topic here at Superuser.  Evidence that this happen is the extremely poor spam post by Pearse.

Comment: You have several different problems and what you're asking is not very clear. Don't assume a solution... Just state your question clearly and we can suggest answers.

You can send out [e-mails through Amazon](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/) so Google does not need to be involved. What your issue is being able to pull e-mail hosted on Google Apps into LabTech?

Comment: is labtech a client or server or both?

Comment: @Ramhound i am not asking for who provides better service. Rather anyone provides this service or a pass-through

Comment: @sunk818 i want emails sent out from a monitoring system(on a dedicated server, where i have no access) to any email. An SSL-less email need to be configured on the system to be able to send-out emails. Iff i had access to the server, i'd have setup a Hmail. I am asking for any other way or the least an SSL-less email service.

Comment: @barlop Labtech is Svr-Clt setup, but it has nothing to do with my requirement

Comment: We dont manage the server. LabTech Inc hosts LabTech servers on EC2 and provide us with just basic access(absolutely no access to EC2). The link shows how to set this up on a managed server. LabTech has notified that they will not be installing 3rd party stuff on dedicated servers..

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to put stunnel on your client machine or your server machine.

You can put it on either, or one in between.

It will listen on some port.

You connect the non-ssl client to that port that stunnel listens on and it will then connect to the ssl server.

Here is a snippet from stunnel.conf  notice the example in there by default, uses gmail!

```
; Example SSL client mode services

;[gmail-pop3]
;client = yes
;accept = 127.0.0.1:110
;connect = pop.gmail.com:995

;[gmail-imap]
;client = yes
;accept = 127.0.0.1:143
;connect = imap.gmail.com:993

[gmail-smtp]
client = yes
accept = 127.0.0.1:345
connect = smtp.gmail.com:465
```

But notice also that the [gmail-smtp] (what you want), only connects to port 465 which is ssl without starttls https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15796530/what-is-the-difference-between-ports-465-and-587

It seems stunnel only supports that form of ssl..

But that's OK because gmail supports that (on port 465).

Comment: LabTech is a Client-Server setup(a monitoring system), but this has nothing to do with my requirement. Apologies for the mess-up. My requirement is simple: Monitoring server need to be configured with an email to send notifications to concerned parties. But SSL emails dont work(cannot be configured on server;surely a pitfall of the system). As the system is hosted on a dedicated server, i cannot install 3rd party email redirectors on the same.

Comment: Because it is on a dedicated server should be precisely why you can install a third party tool such as stunnel

Comment: It is a dedicated server, but not managed by us.

Comment: @pulsarjune ok, good to use @ if you're replying to somebody (and no @ if you're replying to the answer). Also, notice what i'm saying is that you don't have to install stunnel on the server, it can connect to the server like an ssl supporting client.

Comment: @pulsarjune so your 'monitoring server' is an email client that needs to be given  a non-ssl smtp server and non-ssl pop server. stunnel can help there